# I don't know why I keep getting AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python

I keep getting the following error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'size'. The split function also added

```
import numpy as np
def split(array):
    N = {}
    uniqe_array = np.unique(array)
    for i in uniqe_array:
        N[i] = np.where(array==i)
    
    return N




def information_gain(x_array, y_array): 
    parent_entropy = entropy(x_array)
    split_dict = split(y_array)
    for val in split_dict.values():
        freq = val.size / x_array.size
        child_entropy = entropy([x_array[i] for i in val])
        parent_entropy -= child_entropy* freq
    return parent_entropy

x = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]) 
print(round(information_gain(x, y), 4))
x = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2])
y = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]) 
print(round(information_gain(x, y), 4))
```

Comment: attach tracback

Comment: Where do you define 'entropy'? This would cause someone to get a NameError because you didn't define it in the code you provided

Comment: Can you provide the code for function `split`?

Comment: somewhere along the line you're using a .size method on something that is actually a tuple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the values of `split_dict` are tuples and not what I assume to be expected `np.array`'s. I would recommend taking a look at what function `split` is returning to `split_dict` because it might be creating tuples instead of `np.array`'s.

## Edit:

Based on what's inside function `split`, it's returning `{0: (array([0, 2], dtype=int64),), 1: (array([1, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),)}` to `split_dict` so the values are tuples that contain a `numpy.array` and the data type (in this case `int64`) as elements, thus raising the `AttributeError`.

A slightly modified `split` that does what you're looking for would look something like this:

```py
def split(array):
    N={}
    uniqe_array=np.unique(array)
    for i in uniqe_array:
        N[i]=np.where(array==i)[0]     #Notice change here to take first element 
    return N
```

See this answer for more information: [What is the purpose of numpy.where returning a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50646102/what-is-the-purpose-of-numpy-where-returning-a-tuple)

Comment: Do you think my split function has an issue?                                            
    def split(array):
    N={}
    uniqe_array=np.unique(array)
    for i in uniqe_array:
        
        N[i]=np.where(array==i)
    return N

Comment: Could you edit this into a code block? it doesn't have any formatting lol

Comment: I added it. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Could you post the correct form for the split function, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of the function is len and not size

```
objects = (1,2,3)
len(objects)
```

Will give output as 3

Comment: ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Comment: Please share the code for entropy() so we can find out what has gone wrong

Comment: @Mihir I'm not sure function `entropy` is where the error is. It wouldn't be able to modify `x_array` in place to change it's type from a `numpy.array` to a tuple

Comment: I added my entropy function

Comment: @Pouria can you post your `split` function as well?